# LuaJIT setfenv not appearing to set further function calls to the given environment

Tags: lua, luajit

I'm attempting to sandbox some functions using setfenv, and I recieve the following output:

```
123
nil
```

Why is `testValue` when calling `sandboxTest()` `nil`, but it's 123 when it's accessed in `callSandboxedTest()`?

Using LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta2 (Lua 5.1)

```
function sandboxTest()
    print(testValue)
end

local aNumber = 123

function callSandboxedTest()
    setfenv(1, {
        print = print,
        testValue = aNumber,
        sandboxTest = sandboxTest
    })
    print(testValue)
    sandboxTest()
end

callSandboxedTest()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Environments aren't part of the call stack. Every function has its *own* environment. So `sandboxTest` has an environment, as does `callSandboxTest`. Changing the environment of one function has no effect on the environment of another.

`sandboxTest` will continue to use the default environment, so it will access the regular global table to find `testValue`. And since `testValue` is never set in the global table, `sandboxTest` will get `nil`.

That's why, when maintaining a sandbox, it is very important to carefully choose what functionality to expose to the sandbox. If a function needs to be part of the sandbox, then that function needs to have its environment set.

That's why it's best to sandbox based on compiled Lua chunks rather than individual functions. When creating functions, the functions created will inherit the current environment.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't modified the environment that `sandboxTest` is using; you only modified the environment of the current function. You can use `setfenv` to set the environment of a particular function by passing a function name (passing a number modifies the environment of a function in the call stack):

```
setfenv(sandboxTest, {
        print = print,
        testValue = aNumber,
        sandboxTest = sandboxTest
    })
```

This will print `123 123`.